# Removing "Define" from UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I wish to remove the "Define" option from the menu of a UISearchBar that I have placed in my view's nib file.

As widely suggested, I subclassed UISearchBar and then overrode `-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender` to return YES only for cut, copy and paste options.  I then set the custom class of this UISearchBar to the subclass I created, in the nib file.

The method is indeed called, but doesn't work as intended. When I set a breakpoint, and monitor for which actions it is called, it's called for `define:` only on a few occasions (yes, just randomly - it might come up on one run, and might not on the other). Even when it is called for `define:`, and a NO is returned, the "Define" option turns up on the menu.

Is there any way I can fix this? The deployment target for the app is iOS 7.

Comment: The problem with this approach is `UISearchBar` has a very complex and "treacherous" view hierarchy. Most likely, one of the internal text fields (of which there are a few) is catching the `canPerformAction` call and replying positively. There isn't any good solution for this. You can probably achieve this by runtime hackery, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Right, I've seen solutions which suggest looping through subviews, but wouldn't like to do that.

Comment: Indeed. And worse, looping will not be enough for what you need. My advice is to let it be and if really bothering you, open a bug report/feature enhancement with Apple. Make sure to post the `rdar://` number here for other people to duplicate.